# FireBase messaging is not yet resolved

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I am unable to install `Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging version 42.1001.0-beta2` in xamarin forms.

```
Unable to find a version of 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement' that is compatible with 'Xamarin.Firebase.Common 42.1001.0-beta2
constraint: Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement (= 42.1001.0-beta2)', 'Xamarin.Firebase.Iid 42.1001.0-beta2
constraint: Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement (= 42.1001.0-beta2)', 'Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 42.1001.0-beta2
constraint: Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement (= 42.1001.0-beta2)', 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 29.0.0.2-beta1
constraint: Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement (= 29.0.0.2-beta1)', 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm 29.0.0.2-beta1
constraint: Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement (= 29.0.0.2-beta1)', 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Iid 42.1001.0-beta2
constraint: Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement (= 42.1001.0-beta2)', 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Measurement 29.0.0.2-beta1
constraint: Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement (= 29.0.0.2-beta1)', 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks 42.1001.0-beta2
constraint: Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement (= 42.1001.0-beta2)'.
```

I tried from github Firebase samples also, but it's taking 1 month time a go but not resolved. And one more request xamarin forums also no one cannot give solution for Firebase messaging.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. It ended up being to do with the install of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm. My issue, and it appears like it could be your issue, is that you're mixing 42.* with 29.*. I eneded up uninstalling all Google play services libs and installing the 42.* versions.